# Report a partir de DataSet criado em uma Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, relatório, datatable, dataset

Como faço para criar um Report do Visual Studio 2013 a partir de um DataTable (ou DataSet) criado em um método?

Ao buscar a fonte de dados do Report.rdlc eu referencio a classe onde a DataTable é criada, mas ela não é listada como DataSource.

Tentei adicionar um DataSet.xsd ao meu projeto, criei um DataTable com o mesmo schema do que será gerado, mas não consigo populá-lo com os dados do método.

Como devo proceder?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a resposta era mais simples do que eu imaginava.

Apenas estava faltando criar uma instância do DataSet como uma classe qualquer. Achava que não seria necessário mas aprendi na marra que sim.